# Is there a way to round the mouse position in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, mouse

I have tried making a simple system in my game where the player shoots where the mouse position is.
But when i get the mouse position, i get a float tuple (I think that's what it's called)

Is there any way to round the mouse position.

This is the code (I have it changed it so the mouse pos gets printed instead of my whole game, but you get the jyst of it)

```
import pygame as pg

class Game:

    def __init__(self):

        pg.init()
        pg.display.init()

        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()


    def update(self):

        print(pg.mouse.get_pos())


    def run(self):

        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.update()


    def quit(self):

        pg.quit()

g = Game()
while True
g.update()
```

And this is the error

> ```
> self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt ## This is a line of code that makes the movement smooth ##
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
> ```

But as you can see, the output of the `print(pg.mouse.get_pos())` isn't a float. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I don't see `self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt` in your code. Anyway the error says it all. In `self.vel * self.game.dt`, one of them is a sequence and the other is a float. And you can't multiply a sequence by a float

Comment: I did not get a solution

Answer (score 1):

The mouse position is an integral value, but `self.game.dt` is not integral.

If `self.vel` is a list or tuple, `self.vel * self.game.dt` doesn't do what you'd expect. It doesn't multiply each element of the list, it doubles the list.

You must change the components of the coordinate separately:

<s>`self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt`</s>

```py
self.pos = (
    self.pos[0] + self.vel[0]*self.game.dt, 
    self.pos[1] + self.vel[1]*self.game.dt)
```

If `self.pos` is not a tuple but a list, it can be made shorter:

```py
self.pos[0] += self.vel[0]*self.game.dt 
self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]*self.game.dt
```

---

Pygame provides [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) for vector arithmetic.